# Replacing matched record with record present in next column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames A,B

"A" data frame consists of 1 column(column name:str1)

"B" data frame consists of 2 columns(column names:m2,m3)

I am comparing str1 from "A" with m2 of "B"

what i want is when "str1" matches with "m2" i want "str1" to get replaced by "m3".
following is my data,

```
    data frame A.str1="gmaps","facebook","gmail","linkedin"
    data frame B.m1  ="gmaps","oracle","gmail","intel"
    data frame B.m2  ="Google","xyz","Google","nvidia"
```

i want the output as

```
    data frame A.str1="Google","facebook","Google","linkedin"
```

so where ever A.str1 matches with B.m1 the A.str1 will be replaced by B.m2
thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output to this question.  See this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/6361531)  on how to ask a good pandas question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create helper `Series` and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) or use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), but it creates `NaN`s for non matched columns, so is necessary [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'str1': ["gmaps","facebook","gmail","linkedin"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'m1': ["gmaps","oracle","gmail","intel"],
                    'm2': ["Google","xyz","Google","nvidia"]})

s = df2.set_index('m1')['m2']
print (s)
m1
gmaps     Google
oracle       xyz
gmail     Google
intel     nvidia
Name: m2, dtype: object

df1['str1'] = df1['str1'].replace(s)
#alternatives
#df1['str1'] = df1['str1'].map(s).fillna(df1['str1'])
#df1['str1'] = df1['str1'].map(s).combine_first(df1['str1'])
print (df1)

       str1
0    Google
1  facebook
2    Google
3  linkedin
```